# If-statement not filtering out undefined

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to cleanse a dataset, but my if statement appears not to work.

The first part, `x.sites.length>0`, seems to work by itself.
The second part, `(x !== undefined)`, doesn't seem to register at all. In my return Array, some of the `undefined`s are still there. I have tried various different ways of writing `(x !== undefined)`, but none of them seem to work for me.

Any thoughts?

```
export function clenseData(dataset){    


    let cleansedSet = dataset.map(x=>{

        if(x.sites.length>0 && (x !== undefined))
        {return x;}//doesn't work.
    })
    console.log(cleansedSet);
    debugger;
    return cleansedSet;
}



Here is the JSON String for one of the inputs: {"data":{"success":true,"data":[{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Roxanne Modafferi","Valentina Shevchenko"],"commence_time":1555754400,"home_team":"Roxanne Modafferi","sites":[{"site_key":"unibet","site_nice":"Unibet","last_update":1555332974,"odds":{"h2h":[3.35,1.3]}},{"site_key":"nordicbet","site_nice":"Nordic Bet","last_update":1555332998,"odds":{"h2h":[3.8,1.27]}},{"site_key":"sport888","site_nice":"888sport","last_update":1555332928,"odds":{"h2h":[3.35,1.3]}},{"site_key":"marathonbet","site_nice":"Marathon Bet","last_update":1555332887,"odds":{"h2h":[3.75,1.28]}},{"site_key":"williamhill","site_nice":"William Hill","last_update":1555332878,"odds":{"h2h":[3.25,1.33]}}],"sites_count":5},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Marcin Tybura","Shamil Abdurakhimov"],"commence_time":1555754400,"home_team":"Marcin Tybura","sites":[{"site_key":"unibet","site_nice":"Unibet","last_update":1555332974,"odds":{"h2h":[1.57,2.3]}},{"site_key":"matchbook","site_nice":"Matchbook","last_update":1555333223,"odds":{"h2h":[1.63,2.39]}},{"site_key":"nordicbet","site_nice":"Nordic Bet","last_update":1555332998,"odds":{"h2h":[1.55,2.4]}},{"site_key":"sport888","site_nice":"888sport","last_update":1555332928,"odds":{"h2h":[1.57,2.3]}},{"site_key":"marathonbet","site_nice":"Marathon Bet","last_update":1555332887,"odds":{"h2h":[1.6,2.31]}},{"site_key":"williamhill","site_nice":"William Hill","last_update":1555332878,"odds":{"h2h":[1.53,2.38]}}],"sites_count":6},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Aleksei Oleinik","Alistair Overeem"],"commence_time":1555754400,"home_team":"Alistair Overeem","sites":[{"site_key":"unibet","site_nice":"Unibet","last_update":1555332974,"odds":{"h2h":[2.9,1.4]}},{"site_key":"sport888","site_nice":"888sport","last_update":1555332928,"odds":{"h2h":[2.9,1.4]}},{"site_key":"marathonbet","site_nice":"Marathon Bet","last_update":1555332887,"odds":{"h2h":[2.96,1.41]}},{"site_key":"nordicbet","site_nice":"Nordic Bet","last_update":1555332998,"odds":{"h2h":[2.9,1.41]}},{"site_key":"williamhill","site_nice":"William Hill","last_update":1555332878,"odds":{"h2h":[2.9,1.4]}}],"sites_count":5},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Keita Nakamura","Sultan Aliev"],"commence_time":1555754400,"home_team":"Sultan Aliev","sites":[{"site_key":"unibet","site_nice":"Unibet","last_update":1555332974,"odds":{"h2h":[1.8,1.95]}},{"site_key":"matchbook","site_nice":"Matchbook","last_update":1555333223,"odds":{"h2h":[1.85,1.97]}},{"site_key":"nordicbet","site_nice":"Nordic Bet","last_update":1555332998,"odds":{"h2h":[1.81,2]}},{"site_key":"sport888","site_nice":"888sport","last_update":1555332928,"odds":{"h2h":[1.8,1.95]}},{"site_key":"marathonbet","site_nice":"Marathon Bet","last_update":1555332887,"odds":{"h2h":[1.86,1.92]}},{"site_key":"williamhill","site_nice":"William Hill","last_update":1555332878,"odds":{"h2h":[1.8,1.91]}}],"sites_count":6},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Alexander Volkov","Luis Henrique Da Silva"],"commence_time":1555786800,"home_team":"Luis Henrique Da Silva","sites":[{"site_key":"ladbrokes","site_nice":"Ladbrokes","last_update":1555333247,"odds":{"h2h":[1.74,2.05]}},{"site_key":"nordicbet","site_nice":"Nordic Bet","last_update":1555332998,"odds":{"h2h":[1.66,2.23]}},{"site_key":"betfair","site_nice":"Betfair","last_update":1555332863,"odds":{"h2h":[1.66,2.18]}}],"sites_count":3},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Marcin Tybura","Shamil Abdurakhimov"],"commence_time":1555790400,"home_team":"Shamil Abdurakhimov","sites":[{"site_key":"ladbrokes","site_nice":"Ladbrokes","last_update":1555333247,"odds":{"h2h":[1.55,2.4]}},{"site_key":"betfair","site_nice":"Betfair","last_update":1555332863,"odds":{"h2h":[1.53,2.48]}}],"sites_count":2},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Keita Nakamura","Sultan Aliev"],"commence_time":1555790400,"home_team":"Sultan Aliev","sites":[{"site_key":"ladbrokes","site_nice":"Ladbrokes","last_update":1555333247,"odds":{"h2h":[1.8,2]}},{"site_key":"betfair","site_nice":"Betfair","last_update":1555332863,"odds":{"h2h":[1.79,1.99]}}],"sites_count":2},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Roxanne Modafferi","Valentina Shevchenko"],"commence_time":1555790400,"home_team":"Roxanne Modafferi","sites":[{"site_key":"matchbook","site_nice":"Matchbook","last_update":1555333223,"odds":{"h2h":[3.78,1.3]}},{"site_key":"ladbrokes","site_nice":"Ladbrokes","last_update":1555333247,"odds":{"h2h":[3.7,1.27]}},{"site_key":"betfair","site_nice":"Betfair","last_update":1555332863,"odds":{"h2h":[3.45,1.28]}}],"sites_count":3},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Aleksei Oleinik","Alistair Overeem"],"commence_time":1555801200,"home_team":"Aleksei Oleinik","sites":[{"site_key":"betfair","site_nice":"Betfair","last_update":1555332863,"odds":{"h2h":[3.05,1.45]}},{"site_key":"matchbook","site_nice":"Matchbook","last_update":1555333223,"odds":{"h2h":[2.95,1.42]}},{"site_key":"ladbrokes","site_nice":"Ladbrokes","last_update":1555333247,"odds":{"h2h":[3,1.39]}}],"sites_count":3},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Alex Oliveira","Mike Perry"],"commence_time":1556406000,"home_team":"Mike Perry","sites":[],"sites_count":0},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Cory Sandhagen","John Lineker"],"commence_time":1556406000,"home_team":"Cory Sandhagen","sites":[{"site_key":"sport888","site_nice":"888sport","last_update":1555332928,"odds":{"h2h":[2.15,1.65]}},{"site_key":"unibet","site_nice":"Unibet","last_update":1555332974,"odds":{"h2h":[2.15,1.65]}}],"sites_count":2},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Jack Hermansson","Ronaldo Souza"],"commence_time":1556413200,"home_team":"Jack Hermansson","sites":[{"site_key":"nordicbet","site_nice":"Nordic Bet","last_update":1555332998,"odds":{"h2h":[2.15,1.7]}},{"site_key":"sport888","site_nice":"888sport","last_update":1555332928,"odds":{"h2h":[2.25,1.62]}},{"site_key":"unibet","site_nice":"Unibet","last_update":1555332974,"odds":{"h2h":[2.25,1.62]}}],"sites_count":3},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Glover Teixeira","Ion Cutelaba"],"commence_time":1556413200,"home_team":"Glover Teixeira","sites":[{"site_key":"unibet","site_nice":"Unibet","last_update":1555332974,"odds":{"h2h":[2.2,1.62]}},{"site_key":"nordicbet","site_nice":"Nordic Bet","last_update":1555332998,"odds":{"h2h":[2.24,1.65]}},{"site_key":"marathonbet","site_nice":"Marathon Bet","last_update":1555332887,"odds":{"h2h":[2.31,1.63]}},{"site_key":"sport888","site_nice":"888sport","last_update":1555332928,"odds":{"h2h":[2.2,1.62]}}],"sites_count":4},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Court McGee","Dhiego Lima"],"commence_time":1556413200,"home_team":"Court McGee","sites":[{"site_key":"unibet","site_nice":"Unibet","last_update":1555332974,"odds":{"h2h":[1.62,2.2]}},{"site_key":"nordicbet","site_nice":"Nordic Bet","last_update":1555332998,"odds":{"h2h":[1.6,2.33]}},{"site_key":"sport888","site_nice":"888sport","last_update":1555332928,"odds":{"h2h":[1.62,2.2]}}],"sites_count":3},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Andrei Arlovski","Leonardo Augusto Guimaraes"],"commence_time":1556413200,"home_team":"Andrei Arlovski","sites":[{"site_key":"unibet","site_nice":"Unibet","last_update":1555332974,"odds":{"h2h":[2.1,1.68]}},{"site_key":"nordicbet","site_nice":"Nordic Bet","last_update":1555332998,"odds":{"h2h":[2.22,1.66]}},{"site_key":"sport888","site_nice":"888sport","last_update":1555332928,"odds":{"h2h":[2.1,1.68]}}],"sites_count":3},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Jessica Penne","Jodie Esquibel"],"commence_time":1556413200,"home_team":"Jessica Penne","sites":[{"site_key":"unibet","site_nice":"Unibet","last_update":1555332974,"odds":{"h2h":[1.55,2.35]}},{"site_key":"nordicbet","site_nice":"Nordic Bet","last_update":1555332998,"odds":{"h2h":[1.51,2.55]}},{"site_key":"sport888","site_nice":"888sport","last_update":1555332928,"odds":{"h2h":[1.55,2.35]}}],"sites_count":3},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Jason Gonzalez","Jim Miller"],"commence_time":1556413200,"home_team":"Jim Miller","sites":[{"site_key":"unibet","site_nice":"Unibet","last_update":1555332974,"odds":{"h2h":[2.25,1.6]}},{"site_key":"nordicbet","site_nice":"Nordic Bet","last_update":1555332998,"odds":{"h2h":[2.27,1.63]}},{"site_key":"sport888","site_nice":"888sport","last_update":1555332928,"odds":{"h2h":[2.25,1.6]}}],"sites_count":3},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Alex Volkanovski","Jose Aldo"],"commence_time":1557622800,"home_team":"Jose Aldo","sites":[{"site_key":"sport888","site_nice":"888sport","last_update":1555332928,"odds":{"h2h":[2.05,1.72]}},{"site_key":"unibet","site_nice":"Unibet","last_update":1555332974,"odds":{"h2h":[2.05,1.72]}},{"site_key":"nordicbet","site_nice":"Nordic Bet","last_update":1555332998,"odds":{"h2h":[2.09,1.74]}},{"site_key":"marathonbet","site_nice":"Marathon Bet","last_update":1555332887,"odds":{"h2h":[2.12,1.74]}}],"sites_count":4},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Jessica Andrade","Rose Namajunas"],"commence_time":1557626400,"home_team":"Rose Namajunas","sites":[{"site_key":"sport888","site_nice":"888sport","last_update":1555332928,"odds":{"h2h":[1.65,2.2]}},{"site_key":"unibet","site_nice":"Unibet","last_update":1555332974,"odds":{"h2h":[1.65,2.2]}},{"site_key":"nordicbet","site_nice":"Nordic Bet","last_update":1555332998,"odds":{"h2h":[1.71,2.13]}},{"site_key":"marathonbet","site_nice":"Marathon Bet","last_update":1555332887,"odds":{"h2h":[1.7,2.18]}}],"sites_count":4},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Alexander Gustafsson","Ashlee Evans Smith"],"commence_time":1559422800,"home_team":"Alexander Gustafsson","sites":[{"site_key":"unibet","site_nice":"Unibet","last_update":1555332974,"odds":{"h2h":[1.44,2.7]}},{"site_key":"nordicbet","site_nice":"Nordic Bet","last_update":1555332998,"odds":{"h2h":[1.48,2.6]}}],"sites_count":2},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Jessica Eye","Valentina Shevchenko"],"commence_time":1560045600,"home_team":"Valentina Shevchenko","sites":[{"site_key":"unibet","site_nice":"Unibet","last_update":1555332974,"odds":{"h2h":[6,1.12]}},{"site_key":"sport888","site_nice":"888sport","last_update":1555332928,"odds":{"h2h":[6,1.12]}},{"site_key":"nordicbet","site_nice":"Nordic Bet","last_update":1555332998,"odds":{"h2h":[6.25,1.12]}},{"site_key":"marathonbet","site_nice":"Marathon Bet","last_update":1555332887,"odds":{"h2h":[8,1.08]}}],"sites_count":4},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Henry Cejudo","Marlon Moraes"],"commence_time":1560049200,"home_team":"Henry Cejudo","sites":[{"site_key":"unibet","site_nice":"Unibet","last_update":1555332974,"odds":{"h2h":[2.1,1.72]}},{"site_key":"sport888","site_nice":"888sport","last_update":1555332928,"odds":{"h2h":[2.1,1.72]}},{"site_key":"marathonbet","site_nice":"Marathon Bet","last_update":1555332887,"odds":{"h2h":[2.12,1.74]}},{"site_key":"nordicbet","site_nice":"Nordic Bet","last_update":1555332998,"odds":{"h2h":[2.09,1.74]}}],"sites_count":4},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Amanda Nunes","Holly Holm"],"commence_time":1562464800,"home_team":"Amanda Nunes","sites":[{"site_key":"unibet","site_nice":"Unibet","last_update":1555332974,"odds":{"h2h":[1.3,3.45]}},{"site_key":"sport888","site_nice":"888sport","last_update":1555332928,"odds":{"h2h":[1.3,3.45]}},{"site_key":"nordicbet","site_nice":"Nordic Bet","last_update":1555332998,"odds":{"h2h":[1.3,3.5]}},{"site_key":"marathonbet","site_nice":"Marathon Bet","last_update":1555332887,"odds":{"h2h":[1.31,3.52]}}],"sites_count":4},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Jon Jones","Thiago Santos"],"commence_time":1562468400,"home_team":"Jon Jones","sites":[{"site_key":"unibet","site_nice":"Unibet","last_update":1555332974,"odds":{"h2h":[1.14,5.5]}},{"site_key":"sport888","site_nice":"888sport","last_update":1555332928,"odds":{"h2h":[1.14,5.5]}},{"site_key":"nordicbet","site_nice":"Nordic Bet","last_update":1555332998,"odds":{"h2h":[1.17,5]}},{"site_key":"marathonbet","site_nice":"Marathon Bet","last_update":1555332887,"odds":{"h2h":[1.16,5.4]}}],"sites_count":4},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Colby Covington","Kamaru Usman"],"commence_time":1562475600,"home_team":"Colby Covington","sites":[],"sites_count":0},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Dustin Poirier","Khabib Nurmagomedov"],"commence_time":1568523600,"home_team":"Dustin Poirier","sites":[],"sites_count":0},{"sport_key":"mma_mixed_martial_arts","sport_nice":"MMA","teams":["Israel Adesanya","Robert Whittaker"],"commence_time":1569697200,"home_team":"Israel Adesanya","sites":[],"sites_count":0}]},"status":200,"statusText":"","headers":{"x-requests-remaining":"24","content-type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","x-requests-used":"126"},"config":{"transformRequest":{},"transformResponse":{},"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"method":"get","url":"https://api.the-odds-api.com/v3/odds/?apiKey=b80b98e306cbe877f35c7db3804d2d72&sport=mma_mixed_martial_arts&region=uk&mkt=h2h"},"request":{}}
```

Comment: are you trying to `filter` the data? if so you should be using filter function & not map. Map is used when you want to iterate over the data.

Comment: Can you express the problem in a way that doesn't use the word "work"? Tell what you wanted to happen, and what happened instead. Often, specifying those two things will help you see the cause of the problem yourself.

Comment: If `x` was undefined, the first part of the if, `x.sites...` would fail with an exception.

Comment: Can you please provide some example inputs? Because Amy is correct; this should be causing exceptions.

Comment: I managed to get it to work by using filter as suggested. Still no idea why the map method didn't work though :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to `filter` the data? if so you should be using filter function & not map. The `map` is used when you want to iterate over the data.

```
export function clenseData(dataset){    
     let cleansedSet = dataset.filter(x => {
        if(x !== undefined && x.sites.length > 0) {
          return true; // if you want to include it in the cleaned data
        }
     })
     return cleansedSet;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The **every()** method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function:

```
dataset.every((x) => x !== undefined && x.sites.length> 0);
```